# Moving on a sphere in Three.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, three.js

I want to simulate a human walking on a globe. So I tried it like this, but while i stick correctly to the earths surface, the camera angles dont get adjusted properly.

How do I do it, so that the movement behaves everywhere on the globe like it does on the north pole right now?

Any explanations and help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

So I have started a simple react project. It displays earth in a 3d Three.js scene and you are able to move on the earths surface. But the camera doesnt adjust properly...

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { PointerLockControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/PointerLockControls';

class EarthPointerLockControls extends PointerLockControls {
    constructor(camera: any, domElement: any) {
        super(camera, domElement);
    }
  
    getSurfaceNormal(earthMesh: any, radius: any) {
        const nearestPoint = this.getNearestPointOnSphereSurface(this.getObject().position, earthMesh.position, radius);
        return nearestPoint.clone().normalize();
    }
  
    getNearestPointOnSphereSurface(point: any, sphereCenter: any, radius: any) {
        const direction = new THREE.Vector3().subVectors(point, sphereCenter);
        return sphereCenter.clone().add(direction.normalize().multiplyScalar(radius));
    }
}

const ThreeDScene: React.FC = () => {
const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("TEST23")

    // create a raycaster to detect intersections between wave arrows and Earth mesh
    const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();

    let camera: any, scene: any, renderer: any, controls: any, moveForward = false, moveBackward = false, moveLeft = false, moveRight = false;
    let earthMesh: any, sunMesh: any;
    let delta = 0.01;
    let moveSpeed = 5 * delta;

    function init() {
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.z = 5;
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // add the Earth mesh to the scene
        const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        const earthTexture = loader.load('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three-globe/example/img/earth-day.jpg');
        const earthGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(50, 32, 32);
        const earthMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: earthTexture});
        earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(earthGeometry, earthMaterial);
        scene.add(earthMesh);

        // add a Sun light source to the scene
        const sunLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.23, 0, 2);
        sunLight.position.set(0, 0, -450);
        scene.add(sunLight);

        // CONTROLS
        controls = new EarthPointerLockControls(camera, document.body);
        const pitchObject = new THREE.Object3D();
        pitchObject.add(camera);
        controls.getObject().add(pitchObject);
        controls.getObject().position.set(0, 0, 0);
    
        // set up initial camera rotation
        camera.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
        pitchObject.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
    
        // add controls to the scene
        scene.add(controls.getObject());
        
        renderer.domElement.addEventListener('click', function () {
            controls.lock();
        });
    }

    function randomPointOnSphere(center: any, radius: number) {
        const u = Math.random();
        const v = Math.random();
        const theta = 2 * Math.PI * u;
        const phi = Math.acos(2 * v - 1);
        const x = center.x + radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
        const y = center.y + radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
        const z = center.z + radius * Math.cos(phi);
        return new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    // add event listeners for pointer lock and keyboard input
    const onKeyDown = function (event: any) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38: // up
        case 87: // w
            moveForward = true;
            break;
        case 37: // left
        case 65: // a
            moveLeft = true;
            break;
        case 40: // down
        case 83: // s
            moveBackward = true;
            break;
        case 39: // right
        case 68: // d
            moveRight = true;
            break;
        case 187: // +
        moveSpeed += 0.01;
        console.log("MOVESPEED: " + moveSpeed)
            break;
        case 189: // -
            moveSpeed -= 0.01;
            console.log("MOVESPEED: " + moveSpeed)
            if (moveSpeed < 0.1) moveSpeed = 0.01
            break;
        }
    };

    const onKeyUp = function (event: any) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38: // up
        case 87: // w
            moveForward = false;
            break;
        case 37: // left
        case 65: // a
        moveLeft = false;
        break;
        case 40: // down
        case 83: // s
            moveBackward = false;
            break;
        case 39: // right
        case 68: // d
            moveRight = false;
            break;
        }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown, false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp, false);

    const updateCameraPosition = function () {
        const cameraDirection = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        cameraDirection.applyQuaternion(camera.quaternion);
      
        const nearestPoint = controls.getNearestPointOnSphereSurface(camera.position, earthMesh.position, 51);
        const surfaceNormal = controls.getSurfaceNormal(earthMesh, 51);
      
        const localYAxis = surfaceNormal;
      
        if (moveForward) {
          controls.getObject().position.addScaledVector(cameraDirection.projectOnPlane(localYAxis).normalize(), moveSpeed);
        }
      
        if (moveBackward) {
          controls.getObject().position.addScaledVector(cameraDirection.projectOnPlane(localYAxis).normalize(), -moveSpeed);
        }
      
        if (moveLeft) {
          controls.getObject().position.addScaledVector(cameraDirection.cross(localYAxis).normalize(), -moveSpeed);
        }
      
        if (moveRight) {
          controls.getObject().position.addScaledVector(cameraDirection.cross(localYAxis).normalize(), moveSpeed);
        }
      
        // Snap the camera to the Earth's surface
        const snappedPosition = controls.getNearestPointOnSphereSurface(controls.getObject().position, earthMesh.position, 51);
        controls.getObject().position.copy(snappedPosition);
        camera.position.copy(snappedPosition);

      };


    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        updateCameraPosition();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    // resize the renderer on window resize
    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

    init();
    animate();


  }, []);

  return <div ref={containerRef}></div>;
};

export default ThreeDScene;
```

I tried some things but nothing seem to work.